# how to disable "hi you have connected to a logitech controller" in bluestacks

Tags: bluestacks

Every time i open bluestacks the logitech controller popup appears and it blinks through out running of bluestacks, actually its not connected to my system. bluestack version 0.9.6.4092 help me to disable the popup

Answer (score 1):

"Thanks to Nikolaj Ceremsenko :

I am not sure if i am on time, but i found a solution to this.

Go into the program-folder (`for me its C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks`) and look under `UserData` and the folder `InputMapper`.

There you can find a file called `GamePads`.

Create a folder and cut that file out into the new folder (*so you can keep it for later if you decide to use a controller again*).

I do not take any responsibility. I can only say that it worked for me."

The above is quoted from another source. My method was to do this but move both "**GamePads.db**" and "**GamePads.db.cfg**" to this folder.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for helping with this question.  You credit Nikolaj Ceremsenko (or someone quoting Nikolaj), and quote a post from somewhere.  Can you include a link to the source?  That's the proper way to do it.